# include file error in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

**Problem fixed! Thanks a lot for the constructive suggestions!**

I am unable to figure out what is the mistake in the following code. Is there something wrong with the way I am doing includes?

```
// This is utils.h
#ifndef UTILS_H
#define UTILS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

typedef pair<int,int> ii;
typedef vector<int> vi;
typedef vector<ii> vii;
typedef vector<vii> vvii;
typedef stack<int> si;
typedef queue<int> qi;

#define tr(c,i) for(typeof((c).begin()) i = (c).begin() ; i!=(c).end() ; ++i )
#define all(c) (c).begin(),(c).end()
#define cpresent(c,x) (find(all(c),x) != (c).end())

#endif

// ==============================================================
// Below is main.cpp

#include "utils.h"

int main() {
    vi v;
}
```

On compiling "g++ main.cpp"  I get the following error message:

utils.h:13: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
utils.h:14: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
utils.h:15: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
utils.h:16: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
utils.h:17: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
utils.h:18: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
main1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main1.cpp:4: error: ‘vi’ was not declared in this scope
main1.cpp:4: error: expected `;' before ‘v’

What is wrong with this code? The utils.h used to work fine some time back when I did not have the #ifndefs in it.

Comment: A tool for code obfuscation, IMO. I could understand program-specific typedefs like `typedef std::vector<std::string> NameList;`. Also, cpresent could just as well be an inline function. Instead of tr, `BOOST_FOREACH` should be more portable (or find a compiler that supports C++0x's range-based for loops).

Comment: I cannot use BOOST.
And if you can suggest a better typedef for vector<int> that is shorter than typing vector<int> itself, I would gladly appreciate it.

Comment: Typedefs are not mainly for less typing, but for a) more descriptive names, b) mnemonic reasons and c) allow you to more easily switch between types then if declaring the type everywhere explicitly.

Comment: Depends what the vector is for. If it's a list of ages, then `typedef std::vector<int> age_list;` Don't program trying to save key strokes, program to increase readability and solve problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those types (`pair`, `stack`, `queue`, `vector`, etc.) are in the `std` namespace.  You either need to add `using namespace std;` at the top of your file (generally after all of the standard library includes) or fully qualify the type names by adding `std::` in front of them.

Generally, it's better practice to fully qualify the type names than to use `using namespace` to avoid potential collisions between names and to make your code cleaner.  You should *never* use `using namespace std` in header files.

(Along the lines of clean code, you should consider using better, longer names for your types; `ii`, `vii`, and `vvii` are atrocious type names).

Answer (score 3):

`vector` and the like are contained in the namespace `std::`. Do **not** use `using namespace std;` in a header file. Otherwise everyone that includes it gets all of `std::` whether intended or not.

On a side note, if this is a utility header intended to be included in other files, you might wrap up those types and `#define`'s in a namespace. Note `#define`'s don't respect namespaces, so you'd prefix them instead:

```
namespace utility
{
    // ...
    typedef std::queue<int> qi;

    // most would recommend this be in CAPS
    #define utility_tr(c,i) for(typeof((c).begin()) i = (c).begin() ; i!=(c).end() ; ++i )
    // ...    
}
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting he put his code into a namespace; definitely a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Before your typedefs, you should have `using namespace std;`

Also, you may wish to use a less common name than UTILS_H.

Comment: No, he shouldn't. He should fully qualify them, because this is a header file. (And because `using namespace std;` is generally bad practice)

Answer (score 1):

you should write

```
using namespace std;
```

before line

```
typedef pair<int,int> ii;
```

or fully qualify types of stl with `std::`

Comment: For most purposes using namespace std; is sufficient.  While using the std:: operator provides for better variable shadowing (especially if you work with euclidean vectors), its generally unnecessary and leads to obfuscated code.

Its also worth noting, that #include<vector> is the namespace version, #include<vector.h> is not, and thus a valid alternative solution (though not one I'd recommend).

Comment: `std::` is not an operator; `::` is an operator.  `vector.h` is not part of the C++ standard.

Comment: @tzenes: I prefer to use std::-prefix. But, since author of question likes names like ii, vi, vii, I think that it is better to use 'using namespace std' for consistency :)

Comment: If you can tell me what to use instead of vi that is shorter than writing vector<int> itself, but as readable as vector<int> then I would gladly use it. 

I don't see any reason for using typedefs other than writing less.

Comment: `IntVector` and `IntVec` are nice choices.